# How to set MinDate for Date Picker based on cell value us VBA and Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date picker, the minimum value it can be is dependent on the value given in the project start date. I am new to VBA so I am still getting used to using it!

Comment: Is your date picker on a userform? Where is the project start date coming from? What have you done so far? ....

Comment: I am following a tutorial, I have created a User Form, the user can select a date using the Date Picker and it will be displayed in a selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment seems a bit different from your original question. Try the following:

```
Selection = Me.DatePickerName
```

Then format your selected cell as 'Date'.